# Workaround for Many2One or One2Many relationships from non-transient Model to TransientModel in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, erp

I want to create a relationship between non transient model and transient model in ODOO-10. we have create a transient model which does some complex computations, now we want to display this data on a non-transient models form but could not achieve this because of transient and non-transient model relationship restrictions

Comment: What did you want to do with a transient model/wizard ?Do you want to create a new  non-transient model record/edit an existing non-transient model record.

Comment: I have made a transient model which stores some temporary data according to business logic and then we want to display that data table on the Sale Order form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only relationship allowed between a normal Model and transien One is:

```
          T   ---- M2o   ----- > M
          M ------ M2M   ------> T
```

So if you want a behavior like One2many use a Computed Many2many and fill it witch a simple search call.

Answer (score 2):

In your non transient model define a button for opening wizard.

**In Non Transient Model**

```
def open_wiz(self):
    wiz=self.env['your_wizard_name'].create(
        {
        'xn_id':self.id, #your_non transient_model's id #not compulosory
        'field1':feild1_data,
        'field2':field2_data
        }
    return {

                'name':'Display',
                'view_type':'form',
                'view_mode':'form',
                'res_model':'your_wizard_model_name',
                'type':'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_id':wiz.id,
                'target':'new',

            }
```

**In Tansient Model**

If you want to change the data from the wizard and to reflect in your Non Transient Model,call Super of Write function and pass data.
Eg:

```
@api.multi
def write(self,vals):
    res=super(wiz_class_name,self).write(vals)
    self.xn_id.write({'field1':self.data_from_wiz})
    return res
```